# How to turn off the cursor in OpenOffice

Tags: openoffice, cursor

When OpenOffice opens a file in read-only mode, it does not show a cursor, and the arrow keys  (up and down) will move the page instead of the cursor.

(By "cursor", I mean the blinking thing also called "caret" and not the mouse cursor.)

Is there any way to turn off the cursor when the document is not read-only?

Answer (score 2):

I don't find any options to disable the cursor. You can use the mouse wheel to scroll rather than arrow keys for smooth movement while reading.

Answer (score 1):

Try the File | Page Preview menu selection.  You will have to fuss with the Zoom.  The Preview toolbar provides page turning buttons.

PS: For me, it is actually annoying that there is no cursor in read-only documents.  It means you can't select text and copy it, etc.

In OpenOffice, there is no cursor where you can't type.  I suspect that is hard-wired.  (This has got to be an interesting accessibility issue though.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that works on Unix systems. If I remove write-mode from the document (`chmod -w mydoc`), OpenOffice won't diplay a cursor and the arrow keys will move the page.

Comment: Isn't that just making the file read-only?

Answer (score 0):

It annoys me too. OpenOffice should copy Notepad++. In Notepad++, I go Settings > Preferences > Editing > Blink rate. Blink rate is maximum slow, which is a freeze.

**Edit**: Nevermind. Just go Control Panel > Keyboard > Cursor blink rate. I'm on Windows 7 though.

Answer (score 0):

On the Status Bar, "**which is at the bottom, on the left there's page number that is the Status Bar**   click on the area indicating the current mode in order to switch to the other mode:

```
INSRT 
Insert mode is enabled. When in Writer: The text cursor is a blinking vertical line.Click on the area to enable the overwrite mode. (It must be in this format [ INSRT | STD ] then that way problem solved

OVER
The overwrite mode is enabled. When in Writer: The text cursor is a blinking block.Click on the area to enable insert mode.
```